# Assignment to a C++ class method?

Tags: c++

I'm working on an small C++ example, to learn C++. Somebody wrote the main function already which looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    map2d p1(1.,3.);       
    const map2d p2(0.,0.);

    p1.x();            // testing the access to member variable
    p2.x();            // testing the access to member variable

    p1.x() = 3.;       // changing the member variable

    return 0;
}
```

Okay. I created a class with the name map2d. Which works so far up to the point where the member variable has to be changed `p1.x() = 3.;`. My question is, how to do it? My class looks like this this:

```
class map2d
{
    private: 
        double xp, yp;
    public:
        map2d (double xnew, double ynew): xp(xnew), yp(ynew) {}

        double x() const { return xp; }   // here is my problem
};
```

I was thinking to return a reference with `&`, but this didn't worked out. I used something something like:

```
double& x() const { return xp; }
```

Did I make something wrong? Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Try learning about const correctness, then it will all be obvious.

Comment: Did you try reading any of the compiler's error messages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't return a modifiable l-value reference to a non-mutable class member variable from a method that is labeled as being `const`.  By labeling a method as `const`, you are telling the compiler that it doesn't change any data members that aren't labeled as `mutable`, nor does it call any class methods that can change the state of non-mutable class members.

You basically need two overloaded versions of your accessor function:

```
double x() const { return xp; }  //constant version
double& x() { return xp; }       //non-constant version
```

Which version of the overloaded function will be chosen depends on the context of the call to the class method.  This is based on whether the class instance for which the method is being called from is a constant or mutable class reference.  For instance:

```
void func_a(const map2d& map)
{
    double x = map.x();  //calls const version
    /* map.x() = 5;  <== calls const version but you'll get a compiler error
                         for returning a non-l-value on left-hand-side of 
                         assignment operator */
}

void func_b(map2d& map)
{
    map.x() = 5;        //calls non-const version
    double x = map.x()  //still calls non-const version
}
```

Comment: Well you can return an l-value reference from a method that is labeled `const` (for instance, a reference to a static variable), but you can't return a reference to a non-`mutable` _member variable_ from a `const` method

Comment: The last paragraph is misleading. What it should say is that the overload is chosen based on whether the implicit instance argument of the member function call is a constant or a mutable reference.

Comment: Just a question. C++ assume every time I pass a reference that I will change the value except if the value is define as static?

Comment: @PateToni no, C++ assumes that every time you pass a reference you _might_ change the value except if the value is _passed_ by `const` reference

Comment: Another way of saying it is that C++ will not allow you to remove the const-ness of a variable without a cast.  A non-mutable member variable of a const object is const; a non-const reference is not, so C++ will not allow you to return a reference to a non-mutable member variable from a const member function.